# How to print A4 size paper using css in HTML (using classic ASP)

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

I am unable to set fixed HTML size for print on A4 sized paper.
Every time data size changes in content the print format

Comment: Please post some code so we can at least see what the output you have is

Answer (score 0):

i think you can find what you are searching for here :
[paper style without image][

```
.list li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  text-indent: 25px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.list li:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.2s;
  -o-transition:      all 0.2s;
}
```

]

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/KVjFQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Classic asp do nothing with printing a4 size, its the duty of HTML, CSS which structure the page for printing.

Create section with each page, and use the below code to adjust margins, height and width.

If you are printing A4 size.

```
Size : 8.27in and 11.69 inches

@page Section1 {
   size:8.27in 11.69in; 
   margin:.5in .5in .5in .5in; 
   mso-header-margin:.5in; 
   mso-footer-margin:.5in; 
   mso-paper-source:0;
}



div.Section1 {
  page:Section1;
}
```

then create a div with all your content in it.

```
<div class=Section1> 
     type your content here... 
</div>
```

You can find more information about print stylesheets and how to use them [here](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets)